# Autoclick delay with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm having some trouble with a greasemonkey script I am writing. It simulates several clicks on the website tvmuse.eu but is being a little temperamental.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     autoclicker
// @include  *.tvmuse.eu/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

var TargetLinks = $("a:contains('Click here to show.')")

for(var i=0; i < TargetLinks.length; i++){
    //alert(i);
    triggerMouseEvent(TargetLinks[i], "click");
}
```

It is meant to click all of the "click here to show" links on the page. If the alert in the loop is uncommented then it will lick every link however it doesn't work if it is commented. I assume this is because of the delay added by the user accepting the alert but when I try to add a delay with "setTimeout" it makes no difference.

A sample page this could be tested on would be
http://www.tvmuse.eu/tv-shows/The-Legend-of-Korra_31565/season_2/episode_11/

Sorry if this has been asked before but I had a good look and couldn't find a working solution to my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I'm inclined to believe it's not so much the delay, but each time you click the alert, it counts that as an event that triggers your function.  Can you put a $.noop() in there, or link it to something that you are going to do anyway, like move the mouse, or scroll the wheel?

Comment: Perhaps providing an example or a jsfiddle would be helpful.